Understanding a Passage about Linear Partial Differential Equations with Non-constant Coefficients
A passage (translated by me) from Tello del Castillo's Ecuaciones en Derivadas Parciales reads

We now study equations of the form
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^Na_i(t,x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}+b(t,x)u = c(t,x).$$
To solve such equations we must find the curves
$$x(t) = \left(x_1(t),\ldots,x_N(t)\right),$$
defined implicitly by
$$\xi(t,x) = \text{ constant },$$
that satisfy
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt} = a_i(t,x).$$
Introducing the change of variable $(t,\xi)$ we obtain
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{dx_i}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^Na_i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}.$$
Substituting into the original equation gives
$$\frac{du}{dt}+b(t,x(t,\xi))u = c(t,x(t,\xi))$$
which is an ODE.


What exactly is the meaning of $du/dt$ and of $dx_i/dt$? After introducing the change of variables it seems that the chain rule is being applied to $u\circ (x,t)$ i.e. that
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial(u\circ (x,t))}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}.$$
If this was the case, however, we would have $\partial x_i/\partial t = 0$ as opposed to $a_i$.

It is difficult (for me at least) to understand what the author is trying to get across. However, the idea is just to note that if you have a function $u = u(\vec{x}(t), t) = u(x_{1}(t), x_{2}(t), \dots, x_{n}(t), t)$ then by the chain rule the total derivative $du/dt$ is given by $$\frac{du}{dt} = u_{t} + \sum_{i}^{n} u_{x_{i}} \frac{dx_{i}}{dt} \tag1$$ Therefore, using $(1)$, the PDE $$u_{t} + \sum_{i}^{n} a_{i}(\vec{x}, t) u_{x_{i}} + b(\vec{x}, t) u = c(\vec{x}, t) \tag2$$ can be rewritten as the ODE $$\frac{du}{dt} + b(\vec{x}, t) u = c(\vec{x}, t)$$ provided you set $dx_{i}/dt = a_{i}$.

@MatthewCassell Sorry, but I get lost at $(1)$. Is this what you are referring to? I've never a total derivative expressed as such before, but I'll read about it.

Yes, the link you provided is exactly what I am talking about.
